# Using Github Actions with Lektor CMS

Tags: python, github-actions, github-pages, lektor

Basically i have a Lektor project, and i'm trying to to use **Github Actions** for deployment to **Github Pages**

**But** the publish  always fail with this message `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

Here is the complete log :

```
Run lektor deploy ghpages-https
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.3/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lektor/publisher.py:657: DeprecationWarning: 'werkzeug.urls.url_parse' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 3.0. Use 'urllib.parse.urlsplit' instead.
  url = urls.url_parse(str(target))
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.3/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py:545: DeprecationWarning: 'werkzeug.urls.URL' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 3.0. Use the 'urllib.parse' library instead.
  return result_type(scheme, netloc, url, query, fragment)
Deploying to ghpages-https
  Build cache: /home/runner/.cache/lektor/builds/1e169503b08805b6925804c56b34ca69
  Target: ghpages+https://dzc0d3r/codeblog
  hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
  hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
  hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
  hint:
  hint:     git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
  hint:
  hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
  hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
  hint:
  hint:     git branch -m <name>
  Initialized empty Git repository in /home/runner/work/codeblog/codeblog/temp/.deploytempbbbozlcm/scratch/.git/
  From https://github.com/dzc0d3r/codeblog
   * [new branch]      gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.3/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py:170: DeprecationWarning: 'werkzeug.urls.url_decode' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 2.4. Use 'urllib.parse.parse_qs' instead.
  return url_decode(self.query, *args, **kwargs)
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
Done!
```

The `publish.yml` file :

```
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main


jobs:
  publish:
    name: Publish site
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: "3.X"
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        key: ${{ github.ref }}
        path: .cache
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install --upgrade setuptools
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Build site
      run: |
        lektor plugins reinstall
        lektor build --no-prune


    - name: Publish site
      env:
        LEKTOR_DEPLOY_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.LEKTOR_DEPLOY_USERNAME }}
        LEKTOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.LEKTOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD }}
      run: |
        lektor deploy ghpages-https
```

And this is the `codeblog.lektorproject` :

```
[project]
name = codeblog
url = https://dzc0d3r.github.io/codeblog/

[servers.ghpages]
target = ghpages://dzc0d3r/codeblog

[servers.ghpages-https]
target = ghpages+https://dzc0d3r/codeblog

[packages]
lektor-minify = 1.2
lektor-disqus-comments = 0.4.1
lektor-tags = 0.3
```

Any idea, help, step by step guide would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have 2FA? The [lektor documentation](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/deployment/ghpages/#credentials) states that if you have 2-factor authentication enabled you need a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) instead of the normal username and password when using HTTPS.

If I'm not mistaken the [lektor website](https://github.com/lektor/lektor-website) itself is built with lektor, hosted on GitHub Pages and deployed with GitHub Actions, so you can take a look at their [workflow](https://github.com/lektor/lektor-website/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy.yml) and [`.lektorproject`](https://github.com/lektor/lektor-website/blob/master/Website.lektorproject) file for some inspiration.

In their workflow they authenticate using the [`GITHUB_TOKEN` secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) as the personal access token. This secret is automatically created in every Actions workflow for authentication purposes, and can be accessed using `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

Comment: i confirm to you that I have read that on the lektor docs, and I'm using an access token `${{secrets.LEKTOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}}`, and I took a look into workflows from different repos including lektor and beeware.github.io , but I always face this error ... I'll try with temporarily disabling 2FA and see how it goes

Comment: Have you tried using the app token `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` instead of `${{secrets.LEKTOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}}`?

Comment: `${{secrets.LEKTOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}}` is an access token and it's configured .. what do you mean by app token ?

Comment: [`${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) is a token that GitHub automatically creates in every Actions workflow. You can use it in your workflow for authentication without configuring anything. The [lektor website workflow](https://github.com/lektor/lektor-website/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy.yml) deploys using this automatic token.

Comment: using `GITHUB_TOKEN` did the trick, thank you a lot, before i accept your answer  can you edit it to mention using `GITHUB_TOKEN` etc

Comment: Always happy to help. I edited the initial answer.